# Non-resolvable Parent POM for Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am following the Jenkins plugin development tutorial [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/developer/tutorial/create/), and have run into the following issue: When I run `mvn verify`, I get the following error text:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for io.jenkins.plugins:demo:1.0-SNAPSHOT: org.jenkins-ci.plugins:plugin:pom:3.43 was not found in MY_ORGANIZATIONS_LOCAL_REPO during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 4, column 13
 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project io.jenkins.plugins:demo:1.0-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\jleonard\eclipse-workspace\jenkinsdb\demo-plugin\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for io.jenkins.plugins:demo:1.0-SNAPSHOT: org.jenkins-ci.plugins:plugin:pom:3.43 was not found in MY_ORGANIZATIONS_LOCAL_REPO during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 4, column 13 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

I've googled non-resolvable parent POM, but have made little headway. I have tried the following:

- Installed Jenkins on my local machine using port 8000 and the credentials I log into my local machine with.
- Verified that the Jenkins service is running, and is using those credentials.
- Edited my ~/.m2/settings.xml, in accordance with another SO answer I cannot find at time of writing:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
  <settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">

    <pluginGroups>

      <pluginGroup>org.jenkins-ci.tools</pluginGroup>

    </pluginGroups>

    <profiles>

      <!-- Give access to Jenkins plugins -->

      <profile>

        <id>jenkins</id>

        <activation>

          <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>

          <!-- change this to false, if you don't like to have it on per default -->

        </activation>

        <repositories>

          <repository>

            <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>

            <url>https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>

            <name>jenkins</name>
            <releases>
              <enabled>true</enabled>
              <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
              <enabled>true</enabled>
              <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
          </repository>

        </repositories>

        <pluginRepositories>

          <pluginRepository>

            <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>

            <url>https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>

            <name>jenkins</name>
            <releases>
              <enabled>true</enabled>
              <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
              <enabled>true</enabled>
              <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
          </pluginRepository>

        </pluginRepositories>

      </profile>

    </profiles>

    <mirrors>

      <mirror>

        <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>

        <url>https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>

        <mirrorOf>m.g.o-public</mirrorOf>

      </mirror>

      <mirror>

        <id>central</id>

        <name>central</name>

        <url>MY_ORGANIZATIONS_LOCAL_REPO</url>

        <mirrorOf>*,!m.g.o-public</mirrorOf>

      </mirror>

    </mirrors>

    <activeProfiles>
      <activeProfile>jenkins</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
  </settings>
  ```

  Edit: I have the rules setup like this because most of the dependencies are held in the local repo, unsure if this is setup correctly though
- Checked that my JRE has the necessary certificates

I'm unsure what else to try to get it to work. Any advice?

Comment: Maven cannot find your parent pom.   If it is not in the parent directory you need to tell it, and tell it right.

Comment: Right, but this is the "hello world" plugin out of the box, what parent POM is it expecting? I had assumed this was something maven would try to download to .m2, yet it searches MY_ORGANIZATIONS_LOCAL_REPO and not https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/ for it. I know I have to "tell it right", but I don't know how to do that; That's why I'm here!

Answer (score 0):

remove the `<activation></activation>` block and try again.